# django rest framework - override viewsets.ViewSet#retrieve in order to use 2 parameters for lookup resource

Tags: django-rest-framework, routes

I'd like to use two model's attributes to lookup a `Route`'s record

**models.py**

```
class Route(DateTimeModel):
    start_poi = models.ForeignKey(Poi, related_name="start_pois", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    end_poi = models.ForeignKey(Poi, related_name="end_pois", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return 'From %s to %s' % (self.start_poi.slug, self.end_poi.slug)
```

**views.py**

```
class RouteViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get']

    @staticmethod
    def list(request):
        queryset = ...

        serializer = RouteSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    @staticmethod
    def retrieve(request, from_poi_slug, to_poi_slug):
        queryset = ...

        route = get_object_or_404(queryset, from_poi_slug=from_poi_slug, to_poi_slug=to_poi_slug)
        serializer = RouteSerializer(route)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns.extend([
    path(rf'{BASE_API_PATH}/routes/(?P<from_poi_slug>[-\w]+)/(?P<to_poi_slug>[-\w]+)', RouteViewSet),
])
```

I get

> Not Found: /api/v1/routes/xyz/abc
>   [29/Apr/2019 10:07:01] "GET /api/v1/routes/molo-santa-maria/kennedy-ne HTTP/1.1" 404 13191

What am I missing?
How can I properly override `#retrieve` and correctly configure `urls`?

Comment: why `staticmethod`?

Comment: to avoid the reference to self in the method's signature; actually it has been suggested by the IDE (PyCharm) but I think it's unrelated to the question...

Comment: It should be ***instance method*** not `staticmethod`, because `ViewSet` expects its to be a ***instance method***

Comment: okay thx I will change it accordingly

Answer (score 2):

Since you are only using read operations, you could use **`ReadOnlyModelViewSet`**.

```
#views.py
class RouteViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    http_method_names = ['get']

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = ...

        serializer = RouteSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        from_poi_slug = kwargs['from_poi_slug']
        to_poi_slug = kwargs['to_poi_slug']
        queryset = ...

        route = get_object_or_404(queryset, from_poi_slug=from_poi_slug, to_poi_slug=to_poi_slug)
        serializer = RouteSerializer(route)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

and in your `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns.extend([
    path(rf'{BASE_API_PATH}/routes/(<from_poi_slug>)/(<to_poi_slug>)/', RouteViewSet.as_view({"get": "retrieve"})),
])
```

Comment: I get: The `actions` argument must be provided when calling `.as_view()` on a ViewSet. For example `.as_view({'get': 'list'})`. If I add `{'get': 'retrieve'}` I still get a 404

Comment: I finally solved using an `GetRoute(APIView)` but I feel like there must be a more *django-way* of doing it by overriding the `ReadOnlyModelViewSet#retrieve method`

Comment: Did you try {"get":"retrieve"} inside the as_view() ??